# How do I change a user's base dir in OS X

Tags: mac-osx, ftp

I'm configuring a OS X Lion based ftp/sftp server, and I want the user for file transfers to land in a specific directory upon login. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to meddle with the home directory as I'm unsure if the absence of directories like `~/Library` will cause problems. Unlike Linux, OS X doesn't store the base dir in `/etc/passwd` for all users.

Does anyone know how to alter the base dir for a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run `dscl . -read /Users/$USERNAME`

Find the entry for `NFSHomeDirectory`, should read like `NFSHomeDirectory: /Users/$USERNAME`.

To change the entry:

`dscl . -change /Users/$USERNAME NFSHomeDirectory $OLD_USER_HOME $NEW_USER_HOME`

Works for shell logins, you may need to copy files from old home dir to the new home dir to allow GUI logins.

Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1.html

Comment: Perfect, it's fine if the path doesn't change for GUI logins. I just had to add the `record_path` to `-change` to get the 2nd command working. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Comment: One addition to the answer Tim posted: I had to use sudo under an admin account to avoid getting a permission error. Once I did that, though, it worked like a charm. Thanks!